# What might cause 2 GFCI outlets to not reset after a power surge?

Tags: receptacle

There was a small power surge causing lights and tv to flicker. Power is on but 2 GFI outlets are not resetting. I have tried every breaker in my home but nothing is wrong.

Comment: If the GFI outlets have anything connected to the Load side terminals, disconnect that.  Then .. does the outlet trip if there is nothing plugged in, or some known good appliance like a lamp ?  If so it's bad.   If it stops tripping, there may be a fault somewhere down the Load side path.

Answer (score 4):

I had a bad power  surge at a vacation home, tripped half the breakers and fried every GFCI (about 6) in the house.   So your power surge probably fried the GFCIs.  If they worked before the surge and now don't work, that's a pretty clear connection between cause and effect.

With the power to the GFCIs off, pull them out from their boxes, look for damage (probably won't see any), turn the power back on and carefully test for voltage using a digital meter or similar across hot and neutral. If you've got 120v but it won't reset, it's fried, if not you may have to check for a fried breaker, it's not likely the breaker got fried, most likely the GFCIs did.  All you can do is replace them.

Answer (score 3):

So, one of two things happened.

Either the power surge caused a ground fault on these two GFCI circuits, and the GFCIs are working as they should...

...Or the power surge damaged the GFCIs and they need to be replaced.

You'll need to swap at least one of them with a known-good GFCI to determine which of those is the case, though I would bet more on the second, without eliminating the first as a *possible* cause.

You might want to consider a whole-house surge suppressor while shopping for your new GFCIs - those can be very easy if you have extra spaces in your main breaker panel and your panel manufacturer makes one to fit, or slightly more complicated - in any case, they can save you from some power surge damages in the future (they are now required in new installations...)

Answer (score 3):

Don't be in too much of a hurry to replace the "faulty" GFCIs.  GFCIs have one job, detecting a certain type of electrical fault that you don't understand. And since you don't understand it, your first impulse is to "shoot the messenger".

The first thing you do is - you know which outlets are dead because things plugged into them don't work.  **Unplug *everything* from those outlets**. Now try to reset the GFCIs.  If they reset and hold, the problem is that the surge fried one of the plug-in things.  Plug them in *one at a time*.  If the GFCI trips after you plug something in, that appliance has a ground fault (the thing GFCIs detect).

Once all devices are unplugged, if the GFCI still does not reset, it's time to shut off the main circuit breaker and pull the GFCIs out of the junction box.  Identify the "LOAD" terminals on the GFCI.  If any wires are attached to the "Load" terminals, then remove those wires and cap them off safely so they are insulated. Put it all back into the junction box (being careful to make sure nothing bare touches the terminals) and then turn the main breaker back on.   Test the GFCI at this point (with "LOAD" wires disonnected).  If it resets normally *now*, then the wiring on the LOAD side (to the other outlets) has developed a fault, and it's almost certainly in a junction box.  And that's where to focus.

Now if you are down to the bare GFCI with nothing plugged into it, and it refuses to reset, then make sure both power and neutral *is actually reaching* the GFCI.  If you see an LED light on the GFCI that proves it is.  Otherwise swap in a plain receptacle (or a new GFCI) just for testing.  If the plain receptacle has no power, then it's a problem in the wiring between GFCI and breaker.  Which may be in the breaker panel itself.  The #1 place for problems is "back stab" connections in plain outlets.  The #2 place is the neutral bar in the panel.

I hardly need to tell you how to replace a GFCI (except don't confuse Line and Load, in fact hook up Line and test before attaching Load).  I'm mainly saying why not to leap right into replacing it without first testing. Nothing is more frustrating than replacing a GFCI and having the new GFCI do exactly the same thing.  Because then you're out $20 and still have to do all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Might need to replace the two GFIs.

Turn off the breaker/s for those two, and double check there is no power.

Take pictures of how they are wired and replace them the same way.

GFIs do tend to break/stop working more often than regular outlets.  The power surge probably did something to them.